# Tibco Spotfire - Add Column Based on Whether a File is Present in a Location (IronPython?)

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

I have a column that is essentially a list of directory paths in Spotfire. What I would like to do, is add (or realistically, replace) a calculated column that uses that column as the file path and return whether or not a file is present in the folder that path leads to.

I've looked into solutions that involve putting an IronPython script in that would load the os module and look for the file. Problem is, and I don't know IronPython at all, but it seems to not be able to load the os module because it isn't actually IronPython software, but Spotfire.

Any help at all would be very appreciated - thanks in advance